# Align Buttons Horizontally and Show Active Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following four buttons, each that do POST requests hence they're in a form:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="books/all" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-md btn-success" type="submit" value="All Books"></input>
</form>
<form action="books/fiction" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="Fiction"></input>
</form>
<form action="books/biographys" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="Biography"></input>
</form>
<form action="books/new" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="New"></input>
</form>
```

I'm curious how I can

1. align the four buttons horizontally and spaced out equally across the page (so they're not all on one side)
2. how to use JS/JQuery or plain CSS to make whichever button is click to be the one that has the `btn-success` class, while the rest don't.

These are POST requests, but the user will be redirected back onto the page so ideally the button they last clicked should be what is shown as active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the buttons inline-block:

```css
form[action^="books/"] {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="books/all" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-md btn-success" type="submit" value="All Books"></input>
</form>
<form action="books/fiction" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="Fiction"></input>
</form>
<form action="books/biographys" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="Biography"></input>
</form>
<form action="books/new" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="New"></input>
</form>
```

jQuery for classes:

```js
$('form[action^="books/"] > input').on("click", function (event) {
  if (event.target !== this) return; //Event was bubbled to the form
  
  event.preventDefault(); //Prevent the submission, can be removed as it is purely for example
  
  $('form[action^="books/"] > input').removeClass("btn-success");
  
  $(this).addClass("btn-success");
});
```

```css
form[action^="books/"] {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px; /*Fix position*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form action="books/all" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-md btn-success" type="submit" value="All Books"></input>
</form>
<form action="books/fiction" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="Fiction"></input>
</form>
<form action="books/biographys" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="Biography"></input>
</form>
<form action="books/new" method="POST">
  <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="New"></input>
</form>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: if you tilt your head, then yes it is vertical, but the problem is that the texts are rotated 90 degrees!

Comment: Thanks! The simple css is what I was missing. In regards to the jQuery, would that be a matter of assigning IDs to each button, and on each click, remove the class `btn-success` from all other buttons and assign it onto the one that was clicked? Unsure because of the POST request reloading the page

Comment: I will update the comment. Sorry It took so long.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for the css question I think you can look into Flexbox.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

For the second question if made something but I don't know if its the right answer you are looking for.
I don't know if it's possible because if you submit a form the browser refreshes the page, so the page becomes the same as the beginning.
If you change something in the page with JS or jQuery this is gone and it's because of the refresh.

PS I am a beginner on stack overflow, so please give me feedback on my answer if I have something wrong.

```js
$(() => {
  $('.btn').click(function(event) {
    currentButton = event.currentTarget;
    $(currentButton).toggleClass( "btn-success" );
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-md">Example button to test the jQuery</button>
  <form action="#" method="POST">
    <input class="btn btn-md btn-success" type="submit" value="All Books"></input>
  </form>
  <form action="books/fiction" method="POST">
    <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="Fiction"></input>
  </form>
  <form action="books/biographys" method="POST">
    <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="Biography"></input>
  </form>
  <form action="books/new" method="POST">
    <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="New"></input>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Regarding 1

There are multiple options for aligning content. You could use `flexbox`, `grid` or classes using translations to center items. In your case, I would probably use `flexbox`. It is fairly simple to use.

Have a look here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

### Regarding 2

I do not advise you to reload the page with `POST-Requests`.

If it is a hard requirement then you can set the "active" class logic based on the `URL`. That simple `if-else` logic would reside inside the page controller or whatever component you use there.

If this is not a hard requirement, you could just toggle the classes with js. However, this will not be persistent (i.e. lost after a reload). In a single-page application, this would probably be good enough. You could, theoretically, save the selection state to a cookie or session, but I would probably not do that.

There is also the option to have links with a route symbol `#` inside the `href`. It will allow you to have some sort of state within the `URL` without having to reload the page. This will scroll/jump to the element that you reference.

Here in this example below, the selection will be lost after reloading:

```js
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu a.btn');

const selectItem = (i, menuItems) => {
  for (let j = 0; j < menuItems.length; j++) {
    menuItems[j].classList.remove('btn-success');
  }
  menuItems[i].classList.add('btn-success');
}

for (let i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
  menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    selectItem(i, menuItems);
    return false;
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="menu" role="navigation">
  <a href="books/all" class="btn btn-md btn-success" role="button">All books</a>
  <a href="books/fiction" class="btn btn-md" role="button">Fiction</a>
  <a href="books/biography" class="btn btn-md" role="button">Biography</a>
  <a href="books/new" class="btn btn-md" role="button">New</a>
</nav>
```

You could do this instead:

```js
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu a.btn');

const selectItem = (i, menuItems) => {
  for (let j = 0; j < menuItems.length; j++) {
    menuItems[j].classList.remove('btn-success');
  }
  menuItems[i].classList.add('btn-success');
}

for (let i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
  menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    selectItem(i, menuItems);
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="menu" role="navigation">
  <a id=#books/all" href="#books/all" class="btn btn-md btn-success" role="button">All books</a>
  <a id="#books/fiction" href="#books/fiction" class="btn btn-md" role="button">Fiction</a>
  <a id=#books/biography" href="#books/biography" class="btn btn-md" role="button">Biography</a>
  <a id="#books/new"href="#books/new" class="btn btn-md" role="button">New</a>
</nav>
```

The `#` can also be accessed in `CSS` using the `:target` selector.